Problem with sendTransaction
const connection = new Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com');
const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(swapTransaction, 'base64');
const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);
const b = bs58.decode(private_key);
const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(b, {
  skipValidation: true,
});
const wallet = new Wallet(keypair);
transaction.sign([wallet.payer]);
const txid = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, {
  skipPreflight: true,
  maxRetries: 5,
});


Currently is sending transaction but i can't get transactionId from function sendTransaction, yesterday it was working but currently is returning null but i have transaction on my wallet when i open history

The issue might be related to an RPC endpoint delay or a transaction might not be confirmed yet when the response is returned.
Consider using sendAndConfirmTransaction + using trader nodes (with the highest transaction speed).
P.S. I'm a Developer Advocate at Chainstack (the most reliable and fastest nodes).
